# Can't find RSA/NONE/NoPadding provider in JDK 1.8

Tags: cryptography, rsa, encryption, java-8

I've generated a RSA key using 1024 bits and I'm trying cipher a 128 block using RSA with no padding.

```
Cipher cifrador = Cipher.getInstance ("RSA/NONE/NoPadding");
```

However I got this exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/NoPadding
```

I'm using JDK 1.8, is it an error in this JVM version?

Comment: Note that RSA without padding is not secure.

Comment: Unfortunately is a requisite from Brazilian government.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle provider (SunJCE) [only supports `"ECB"` mode](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#cipherTable) (which is the same as `"NONE"`). `"NONE"` isn't supported in Java 7 either.